# Import from packages __init__

Tags: python

I got problem I'm not able to fix although I tried almost everything I know or could read somewhere else.

I got a package with this structure:

```
package/
__init__.py
    file.py
    file2.py
    file3.py
    subpackage/
        __init__.py
        submodule1.py
        submodule2.py
```

Lets say I have variable 'db' declared in package/**init**.py and I want to import db into file.py, would I do it as:

file1.py:

from package import db

?

Comment: Is it an import loop? project/__init__.py imports views.py, and views.py imports project/__init__.py?

Comment: Yes, see in the comment Brandon Craig Rhodes answer for further explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Try `from project_top.project import db` oder better delete the `__init__.py` in the directory `project_top` because that doesn't look like that it is meant to be a package.

Comment: Ah, so true. But it doesn't solve the problem anyway - although I really thought this could be it.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should never put anything into your `__init__.py` files except perhaps for constants that do not depend on anything else being imported, because — as you have discovered — anything in `__init__.py` that needs to import things from deeper levels of your tree can cause import loops when those deeper levels them themselves try to perform imports that cross the still-under-construction `__init__.py` space.

Comment: Probably an immortant point. But it's no factor for my problem - I put out the stuff from the `__init__.py` into a regular file but it didn't change anything.

Comment: To expand on this a little: it's OK for two modules to import each other. What is not OK is for those modules to start trying to use each others' *contents* while they're being imported. In this case, if this is really an import loop, both modules are still in the middle of being imported when one module tries to import the other module's `db` attribute—which hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: Ah, now I got that right. Well I know that it is an import loop and also did when i created it. The point is, that I use the Flask framework and in its documentation it's also mentioned that it is an import loop but which is okay at this point.
But it's possible that this loop becomes a problem as soon as `db` is added. But using a `db` object is nothing uncommon for the Flask framework - no idea how to do it somehow else.